# Concatenate number sequence with mathematical operator without executing the operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, api, concatenation

I have to concatenate this DOI of a paper "10.1145/3175684.3175695" at the end of a URL `http://api.semanticscholar.org/v1/paper/`. But when I try to do it, python concatenates the divided result. Is there a way to tell python to not treat the `/` symbol in the middle of `10.1145/3175684.3175695` as a division operator.

```
id = 10.1145/3175684.3175695
url = '{}{}'.format("http://api.semanticscholar.org/v1/paper/",id)
# Make a get request with the parameters.
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.content)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show an example of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is due to the fact that you're not wrapping your DOI number in quotes to make it a string. You'll notice that the base URL, which is a string, has forward slashes in it, but is not having the same issue.

You have the following:

```
doi = 10.1145/3175684.3175695
```

Which python interprets as a mathematical expression like this:

```
doi = 10.1145 / 3175684.3175695
```

You need to wrap it in single (or double) quotes to make it a string literal:

```
doi = '10.1145/3175684.3175695'
base_url = 'http://api.semanticscholar.org/v1/paper/'
url = base_url + doi
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "http://api.semanticscholar.org/v1/paper/"
v =  "10.1145/3175684.3175695"
t = s+v
```

`t` will result in

```
 'http://api.semanticscholar.org/v1/paper/10.1145/3175684.3175695'
```